# Connecte PDO to Sql Server

Tags: php, database, pdo, sqlsrv

i can't have a connection between pdo and my local sql server

my php version is 7.3

this is my connection code

```
$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=127.0.0.1;Database=test","","");

$conn->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
```

i have already installed sqlsrv drivers & extensions for php

Comment: Do you have an error ?

Answer (score 0):

A couple of questions to pin-point the problem:

1. What error is it throwing? (clues to the problem)
2. Is the connection string correct?  (Can you connect to the database using the same string elsewhere?)
3. Can you connect to another database from the code? (Maybe it's the database)

This should help narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i have fixed the problem yesterday
i just used

$conn = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=localhost;Database=test","sqlsrvr","******");

and it did work very well